# Ejecutar JavaFX en web

Tags: javafx, jar, jnlp

He programado una App en JavaFX, que al exportarlo general el JAR, archivo JNLP (que lanza el jar) y también genera un archivo html para poder ejecutar la app en el navegador.
Pero para lanzarlo en una web, aparece el aviso de bloqueado porque no es seguro. He leído que un motivo es que la app no está firmada...

Este es el código del HTML que genera NetBeans:

```
   <html><head>
  <SCRIPT src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
        dtjava.launch(            {
                url : 'AppEscola.jnlp',
                jnlp_content : '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'
            },
            {
                javafx : '8.0+'
            },
            {}
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function javafxEmbedappescola() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                id : 'appescola',
                url : 'AppEscola.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : '800',
                height : '600',
                jnlp_content : 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPGpubHAgc3BlYz0iMS4wIiB4bWxuczpqZng9Imh0dHA6Ly9qYXZhZnguY29tIiBocmVmPSJBcHBFc2NvbGEuam5scCI+CiAgPGluZm9ybWF0aW9uPgogICAgPHRpdGxlPkFwcEVzY29sYTwvdGl0bGU+CiAgICA8dmVuZG9yPmFsZXg8L3ZlbmRvcj4KICAgIDxkZXNjcmlwdGlvbj5udWxsPC9kZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4KICAgIDxvZmZsaW5lLWFsbG93ZWQvPgogIDwvaW5mb3JtYXRpb24+CiAgPHJlc291cmNlcz4KICAgIDxqMnNlIHZlcnNpb249IjEuNisiIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9qYXZhLnN1bi5jb20vcHJvZHVjdHMvYXV0b2RsL2oyc2UiLz4KICAgIDxqYXIgaHJlZj0iQXBwRXNjb2xhLmphciIgc2l6ZT0iNTkwMTY0IiBkb3dubG9hZD0iZWFnZXIiIC8+CiAgICA8amFyIGhyZWY9ImxpYi9qYXZheC5wZXJzaXN0ZW5jZS0yLjIuMS5qYXIiIHNpemU9IjIwMzQyNiIgZG93bmxvYWQ9ImVhZ2VyIiAvPgogICAgPGphciBocmVmPSJsaWIvbXlzcWwtY29ubmVjdG9yLWphdmEtOC4wLjIzLmphciIgc2l6ZT0iMjQxNTIxMSIgZG93bmxvYWQ9ImVhZ2VyIiAvPgogICAgPGphciBocmVmPSJsaWIvb3JnLmVjbGlwc2UucGVyc2lzdGVuY2UuYW50bHItMi43LjcuamFyIiBzaXplPSIxNDc1ODAiIGRvd25sb2FkPSJlYWdlciIgLz4KICAgIDxqYXIgaHJlZj0ibGliL29yZy5lY2xpcHNlLnBlcnNpc3RlbmNlLmFzbS0yLjcuNy5qYXIiIHNpemU9IjQ4NzcwOSIgZG93bmxvYWQ9ImVhZ2VyIiAvPgogICAgPGphciBocmVmPSJsaWIvb3JnLmVjbGlwc2UucGVyc2lzdGVuY2UuY29yZS0yLjcuNy5qYXIiIHNpemU9IjUxODg3NTAiIGRvd25sb2FkPSJlYWdlciIgLz4KICAgIDxqYXIgaHJlZj0ibGliL29yZy5lY2xpcHNlLnBlcnNpc3RlbmNlLmpwYS0yLjcuNy5qYXIiIHNpemU9IjE0MDkxODUiIGRvd25sb2FkPSJlYWdlciIgLz4KICAgIDxqYXIgaHJlZj0ibGliL29yZy5lY2xpcHNlLnBlcnNpc3RlbmNlLmpwYS5qcHFsLTIuNy43LmphciIgc2l6ZT0iMTMzMjk5NiIgZG93bmxvYWQ9ImVhZ2VyIiAvPgogICAgPGphciBocmVmPSJsaWIvb3JnLmVjbGlwc2UucGVyc2lzdGVuY2UubW94eS0yLjcuNy5qYXIiIHNpemU9IjYyMTE4MyIgZG93bmxvYWQ9ImVhZ2VyIiAvPgogIDwvcmVzb3VyY2VzPgogIDxqZng6amF2YWZ4LWRlc2MgIHdpZHRoPSI4MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNjAwIiBtYWluLWNsYXNzPSJhcHBlc2NvbGEuQXBwRXNjb2xhIiAgbmFtZT0iQXBwRXNjb2xhIiAvPgogIDx1cGRhdGUgY2hlY2s9ImFsd2F5cyIvPgo8L2pubHA+Cg=='
            },
            {
                javafx : '8.0+'
            },
            {}
        );
    }
    <!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbedappescola);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>AppEscola</b></h2>
  <b>Webstart:</b> <a href='AppEscola.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication('AppEscola.jnlp');">click to launch this app as webstart</a><br><hr><br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

Adjunto imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]